# El diccionario de parámetros contiene una entrada NULL para el parámetro 'idEstatus' - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, crud

Estoy haciendo un CRUD en ASP.NET MVC pero no queda mi método de edición, ya estoy probando varias formas de hacerlo y en mi último intento me aparece el siguiente error al dar click en el botón de editar.

> El diccionario de parámetros contiene una entrada NULL para el
>   parámetro 'idPerfil' del tipo que no acepta valores NULL
>   'System.Int32' del método 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Update (Int32)'
>   en 'AdministraZion.Controllers.PerfilesController'. Un parámetro
>   opcional debe ser un tipo de referencia, un tipo que acepta valores
>   NULL o debe declararse como parámetro opcional. Nombre del parámetro:
>   parámetros

Aquí dejo el código completo, espero que puedan ayudar con mi problema.

Esto es mi **ViewModel** (PerfilViewModel)

```
public class PerfilViewModel
{
    public int idPerfil { get; set; }
    public string descripcion { get; set; }
    public int idEstatus { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Estatus { get; set; }
}
```

Este es mi **Controller** (PerfilesController)

```
public ActionResult Update(int idPerfil)
{
    PerfilViewModel vm = new PerfilViewModel();
    using (OrganizacionEntities2 db = new OrganizacionEntities2())
    {
        var t = db.catPerfiles.Find(idPerfil);
        vm.descripcion = t.descripcion;
        vm.idEstatus = (int)t.idEstatus;
        vm.idPerfil = t.idPerfil;
    }

    ViewBag.Estatus = db.catEstatus.Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = x.descripcion,
        Value = x.idEstatus.ToString()
    }).ToList();

    return View(vm);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(PerfilViewModel vm)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (OrganizacionEntities2 db = new OrganizacionEntities2())
            {
                var t = db.catPerfiles.Find(vm.idPerfil);
                t.descripcion = vm.descripcion;
                t.idEstatus = vm.idEstatus;

                db.Entry(t).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                ViewBag.successMessage = "Estatus agregado con exito";
            }
            return Redirect("/Perfiles/");
        }

        ViewBag.Estatus = db.catEstatus.Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = x.descripcion,
            Value = x.idEstatus.ToString()
        }).ToList();

        return View(vm);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ViewBag.successMessage = "Ocurrio un error, reintente por favor";
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Ésta es mi **View** (Update)

```
@model AdministraZion.ViewModels.PerfilViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Perfiles", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(d => d.idPerfil)
    <div class="box-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputDescripcion" class="form-control-label mt-3 ml-5">Descripción:</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.descripcion, "", new { @class = "form-control ml-5", style = "width:92%" })
    </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEstatus" class="form-control-label ml-5">Estatus:</label>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.idEstatus, new SelectList(ViewBag.Estatus, "Value", "Text"), "--- Selecciona ---", new { @class = "form-control ml-5", style = "width:92%" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-footer" style="text-align:center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn block btn-success mb-3" style="width: 30%" name="crear">Crear <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button>
    </div>
}
```

Mi **Route.Config**

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Error de código fuente:

> Se ha generado una excepción no controlada durante la ejecución de la
>   solicitud Web actual. La información sobre el origen y la ubicación de
>   la excepción pueden identificarse utilizando la excepción del
>   seguimiento de la pila siguiente.

Éste es el seguimiento de la pila:

> [ArgumentException: El diccionario de parámetros contiene una entrada NULL para el parámetro 'idPerfil' del tipo que no acepta valores NULL 'System.Int32' del método 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Update(Int32)' en 'AdministraZion.Controllers.PerfilesController'. Un parámetro opcional debe ser un tipo de referencia, un tipo que acepte valores NULL o debe declararse como parámetro opcional.
>   Nombre del parámetro: parameters]
>      System.Web.Mvc.ActionDescriptor.ExtractParameterFromDictionary(ParameterInfo parameterInfo, IDictionary2 parameters, MethodInfo methodInfo) +527
>      System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary2 parameters) +91
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary2 parameters) +27
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c.b__9_0(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__11_0() +50
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_1.b__2() +228
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.b__3() +35
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c.b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +11
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c.b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +13
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c.b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +28
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9849569
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +50
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +163

Comment: Hola, indica por favor cómo estás llamando al método GET `public ActionResult Update(int idPerfil)`. Ya que parece que el parámetro `int idPerfil` está llegando a NULL.

Comment: @RafaelAcosta Según yo lo estoy llamando en la Vista en éstas líneas: `@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Perfiles", FormMethod.Post))` y `@Html.HiddenFor(d => d.idPerfil)`. Ya edité mi pregunta con el seguimiento de la pila por si eso ayuda.

Comment: Esa es la llamada POST, yo te digo la llamada GET, al método `public ActionResult Update(int idPerfil)`, donde le pasas el **IdPerfil**.

Comment: La llamada debe ser algo así: `~/Perfiles/update/7` .. donde 7 es tu **IdPerfil**.

Comment: En la Vista Index() ?. Tienes una Vista Index() en  tu proyecto?

Comment: @RafaelAcosta Ah sí, ya te entendí, aquí está: `<a href="/Perfiles/Update/@item.idPerfil" id="editar" class="tippy d-inline-block btn-edit" data-tippy-animation="perspective" data-tippy-arrow="true" title="Edit"><i class="icon-pencil mr-2 text-info"></i></a>`

Comment: @MonseMontoya por favor no coloques la leyenda de resuelto a tu pregunta, con marcar la respuesta que te ayudo como aceptada alcanza

Comment: @Aprendiz Ok, error de novata, gracias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En tu controlador, reemplaza:

```
public ActionResult Update(int idPerfil)
```

Por:

```
public ActionResult Update(int id)
```

El motivo está en route.config:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", //Aquí le estás diciendo que vas a recibir "id"
            defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Si deseas otra alternativa, puedes usar el atributo [Route] en el action del controlador, de esta manera:

```
[Route("Update/{idPerfil:int}")]
public ActionResult Update(int idPerfil)
```

Lectura recomendada: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/