# Obtener valores que se envían desde un fetch Post a mi controlador ASP.NET Framework 4.8

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, fetch

Buenos días estimados colegas mi problema esta en que no logro recibir los datos de una solicitud http usando fetch en mi controlador, les dejo mi código para ver si me pueden echar una mano

con un fetch envió los datos a mi controlador

´´´

```
        let valoresCheck = [];
        let nombre = document.getElementById("inputNombre").value;
        let tipo = document.getElementById("inputTipo").value;

        $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function () {
            valoresCheck.push(this.value);
        });

        let datos = { nombre: nombre, tipo: tipo }
        const data = [datos, valoresCheck];

        console.log(data);

        fetch('@Url.Content("~/Zona/Nuevo")', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(datos => {
            cantdata = datos.data.length;


        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
```

´´´

en mi controlador solo recibo null

´´´

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Nuevo(NuevaZona data)
    {
        try
        {
            using (GenetecEntities db = new GenetecEntities())
            {

                return Json(new { mensage = "exitoso", data = data });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }

    }
```

´´´

clase

´´´´

```
public class NuevaZona
{
    public string[] datos { set; get; }
    public int[] valoresCheck { set; get; }
}
```

´´´

los datos que inprime la consola son los siguiente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Respuesta Relacionada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/299951/822

Answer (score 0):

Analicemos tu código:

en tu fetch tienes:

- `body: JSON.stringify(data),`

y en tu controlador:

- `public ActionResult Nuevo(NuevaZona data)`

Así que le estas pasando un string, tu controlador espera recibir un objeto, puedes solucionarlo si cambias el objeto a string y lo reconviertes en el controlador.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Nuevo(string data)
{
    NuevaZona conversion = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NuevaZona>(data);
    try
    {
        using (GenetecEntities db = new GenetecEntities())
        {

            return Json(new { mensage = "exitoso", data = data });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }

}
```

JsonConvert es una propiedad de [Newtonsoft](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) te dejo otra [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/370459/101499) respecto al tema

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta amigo, pero sigo con el mismo problema haciendo el cambio que me sugeriste me sigue llegando null

Answer (score 0):

Me ocurrió lo mismo, lo solucioné agregando la etiqueta [FromBody] en el parámetro del controlador.

Tu código del controlador quedaría así:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Nuevo([FromBody] NuevaZona data)
    {
        try
        {
            using (GenetecEntities db = new GenetecEntities())
            {

                return Json(new { mensage = "exitoso", data = data });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }

    }
```

Imagino que tienes la libreria importada Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc

En caso contrario, deberás importarla con un:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
```